# Is Java is an "island" for developing new apps and libraries?

Tags: java, web-applications, mono, windowbuilder

I will be making a cross-platform, graphical mathematical modeling application, for example, a user can drop a bunch of nodes on a canvas, specify some mathematical relationships between them, and run a simulation. I'm also interested in seeing in this being a web app.

I have had some programming experience in Java, MATLAB, Python, but I have never made a large application, thus I know very little about software architecture, and how multiple languages work together.

I am trying to figure out the best IDE, language(s), etc., to work in. The previous work done by my group has a lot of C/C++ libraries to draw from for back-end work, like simulation. I was told by my boss that Java is an "island" for development, meaning the Java app has difficulty using libraries from other languages and making its own libraries usable to other languages.

Is this true? Can someone shed some light on this topic?

Also, then **what tools should I be using**? I am ready to learn anything, but I'm trying to go for what would be the **most productive** route. Learning and then programming everything in C/C++ does not seem like a very productive route to me currently.

Things I've looked at so far include WindowBuilder/GWT Designer (this seems like a way to make both desktop and web apps), Mono/GTK+/MonoDevelop, and Delphi

Please feel free to be as verbose as you can, thanks!

Comment: Java can work with non-Java code via the JNI. Alternatively non-Java code can call Java, either by instantiating a JVM or by calling Java that's compiled to machine code. So the "island" judgment is subjective.

Comment: You should figure out a basic plan, then based on what you need to know immediately to get started, take a small part of your question and re-ask it.  Defer decisions until you need to make them.  No one understands the problem as well as you do so you won't get useful advice unless you ask a more specific question.

Comment: It's very easy to integrate Java code with MATLAB. You can [import and call Java](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/matlab_external/f44062.html) directly from within a MATLAB program. Calling a live copy of MATLAB from Java can be done with [matlabcontrol](http://code.google.com/p/matlabcontrol/). For a standalone application you need an extra product, but [MATLAB Builder for Java](http://www.mathworks.com/products/javabuilder/) will let you create standalone Java classes from MATLAB code, which can be called from a web app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fear this post may get closed as off-topic.  But it seems a little too specific to toss, IMHO.

Java interoperates with a lot of non-Java projects, products, etc.  However, a major feature of it is portability, so you'll find that folks go out of their way to stay within the JVM environment.  In that sense it's an "island".

I suggest you think about exactly what you want to interoperate with and get specific - see whether the hooks are there or not.

For your back-end C/C++ libraries, you'll need to implement JNI interfaces.  I'd describe this as having a small but moderately steep learning curve - not a lot to learn, but it takes a little thought - especially if the amount of data passed back and forth is so large that performance is an issue.

You *may* find that you don't have what you need with GWT for the graphical aspects of what you're doing.

I'd think hard about how much you need the web aspect.  If you do, *consider* skipping a desktop-only solution (and maybe Java/GWT) altogether, and just going to the web.  This is especially viable if you don't need to support older browsers.

I'm not going to touch the "what tools" question - it's too broad.

Answer (score 1):

Considering Jython, Groovy, Clojure, and a whole host of other language adaptations for Java, I would firmly suggest that your boss does not know what he is talking about. Java also has the ability to execute native code if necessary, so it is not terribly difficult to incorporate other, non-JVM toolkits. But even if he were right and there was no cross-linguistic work with Java, the language has been around long enough, and it is verbose enough, that you can generally find libraries which will supply the inter-operability you're looking for.

---

Without knowing more about your specifics it will be hard to give a precise answer, but the general rule is that the language you know is better than the language you don't, so unless your language goes completely against the idioms required, use it. Eg. if you have in-house expertise in C/C++, those languages are perfectly adequate for building applications. JavaScript significantly less so.

You do not want bugs which are caused by faulty assumptions about the language. Those are nearly impossible to track, especially since you won't know where to look.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if cross platform is an issue, I would suggest developing in Java, it makes everything very easy in that regard.  As far as loading C/C++ libraries, I don't have much experience with it, but I would recommend taking a look at something like [Java Native Access](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Access).

As far as tools go, they are wide and varied.  I personally use [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org) or [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/), but untimely that sort of choice comes down to what plugins you may need and what you personally prefer.

All in all, I would say program out a little stub of the application in different environments and different languages and see what you like. You really need to know the details of the application to make an informed decision, and it varies in most cases. Best of luck!